# Remove rows that doesn't contain a certain value in column Java

Tags: java, arrays, csv, row

Is there a way I can remove rows that doesn't contain a value between 0-23 in column 3. I have 18 column in total and I am using `bufferReader` to read it. The file I am reading from in CSV file and is a table.

```
public class CSVFileread {
    private final ArrayList<String[]> Rs = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    private String[] OneRow;

    public ArrayList<String[]> ReadCSVfile(File DataFile) {
        try {
            BufferedReader brd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(DataFile));
            brd.readLine();
            while (brd.ready()) {


                String st = brd.readLine().trim();


                OneRow = st.split(",");
                Rs.add(OneRow);

                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(OneRow));
            } 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"System couldn't find the csv file");
            //System.out.println("File not found:" + errmsg);
        } 
        return Rs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just check the value in the third column and if it's not valid don't add it to the list?

Comment: try learning about java naming standards as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while (brd.ready()) {
    String st = brd.readLine().trim();

    OneRow = st.split(",");
    int value = Integer.valueOf(OneRow[2]);
    if (value < 0 || value > 23) {
        Rs.add(OneRow);
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(OneRow));
}
```

Notes: You should only use lowercase letters when beginning a variable or method name.  Uppercase should be used for class names.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you stream the lines and then filter out the rows you don't want to store. Something like the following:

```
List<String[]> rows = bufferedReader.lines()
    .map(l -> l.trim().split(","))
    .filter(r -> Integer.valueOf(r[2]) >= 0 && Integer.valueOf(r[2]) <= 23)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Having said that I recommend you create a class for the rows with meaningful fields for the 18 columns and then encapsulate the translation and filtering logic in your class.

So, for example, if your rows represent students then your code would be something like:

```
class Student {
    public static Optional<Student> fromCSV(String csvLine) {
        String[] fields = csvLine.trim().split(",");
        int age = Integer.valueOf(fields[2]);
        ...
        if (age >= 0 && age <= 23)
            return Optional.of(new Student(..., age, ...));
        else
            return Optional.empty();
    }
}

List<Student> students = bufferedReader.lines()
    .map(Student::fromCSV)
    .filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get);
```